# Which testnet am I on?

Tags: bitcoind, testnet

How can I know which testnet am I on?

I just ran `bitcoind -testnet`, and I would assume it would connect to the most recent one, but is there a way to *know* it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Bitcoin and bitcoind versions v0.3.14 - v0.3.19 used the first testnet.
- Bitcoin, Bitcoin-Qt and bitcoind versions v0.3.20 - v0.6.1 used the second testnet.
- Bitcoin-Qt and bitcoind version v0.7.0 and above use the third testnet.

Comment: Oh, so it's hardcoded in the client, I didn't know that.

Comment: The different testnets have slightly different rules, and a separate genesis block, so yes, they are hardcoded. No point in trying to support multiple versions.

Answer (score 1):

To double check, the genesis block for testnet3 (the current version as of this writing) has hash `000000000933ea01ad0ee984209779baaec3ced90fa3f408719526f8d77f4943`.  So with the daemon running, you can do

```
 bitcoind -testnet getblock 000000000933ea01ad0ee984209779baaec3ced90fa3f408719526f8d77f4943
```

If you are really on testnet3, you should see "height: 0" in the output.